# Find the value A given a function and two intervals

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x) = 5 (x - 2)^{\frac{2}{3}}$. For this function there are two important intervals: $(-\infty,A)$ and $(A,\infty)$. Where $A$ is a critical number.Find $A$, and tell whether $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing for the intervals: $(-\infty,A)$ and $(A,
infty)$. So far I have set $f'(x)$ to zero, but when I try to get critical numbers from this, I am getting $(\frac{10}{3})^{\frac{1}{2}}+2$, which would equal $A$, but that is incorrect. 
I know how to figure out if the intervals are Increasing or Decreasing once I have the value of $A$, but I can't properly find the value of $A$ for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $A=2$, which we don't have to do any manipulations to see what number gives us the zero function after evaluation. Now just ask yourself when is $(x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}< 0$ ,  or equivalently $x-2<0$ and you want to know when is $x-2>0$ (you can verify). This will tell you if the function is increasing or decreasing on the intervals.

$\textbf{Solving for A}$: Get derivative first, $$f'(x)=\frac{10}{3(x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$ then get rid of radical in denominator and set equal to zero,

$$\frac{10}{3} \cdot \frac{(x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{((x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}})(x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=0 $$

Lastly, multiply out and your done.

Comment: But I'm still confused how you got to the conclusion A=2. Could you show the math? I know to do it the derivative would be set to zero, but I guess I must be doing the algebra wrong.

Comment: @Natalie Check the edit.

Comment: Thank you!This really helped!